# jQuery/Ajax : image slider

Tags: jquery, ajax

There is a row which can accommodate only three images at once but i have several images in server and all i want to fetch. so in that case i need image slider.

Let say there are 10 images e.g. `img_1,img_2,img_3,........img_10` and a row & it contains only three `images img_1, img_2, img_3` alongwith `Left_slider_button & Right_slider_button`. What i want? When click on slider_button the images should forward in button direction one by one.
Suppose if i click on `left_slider_button` then `img_2, img_3, img_4` should be in row instead of `img_1, img_2, img_3`. So There is one image forwarded to left direction and one new image fetched as `img_4.`

please give me some tips. I guess `AJAX` would be more useful to fetch the images from server, Right?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your image names in an array and then loop through them. I used three div's to hold the images but you could use anything.

```
$(function () {
    var images = ["img_1", "img_2", "img_3", "img_4", "img_5", "img_6", "img_7", "img_8", "img_9", "img_10"],
        curIndex = 0,
        gotoImage = function (index) {
            $('#images div').each(function (i) {
               var image = curIndex + i;
                if (image >= images.length) {
                    image = image - images.length;
                }
               $(this).html(images[image]);
               // Use something like this to show images instead of text
               // $(this).html('<img src="' + images[image] + '.jpg" />');
            });            
        };

    $('.prev').click(function (e) {
        curIndex--;
        if (curIndex === -1) {
            curIndex = images.length - 1;
        }
        gotoImage(curIndex);
    });

    $('.next').click(function (e) {
        curIndex++;
        if (curIndex === images.length) {
            curIndex = 0;
        }
        gotoImage(curIndex);
    });
});
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/rustyjeans/c3sJW/

There's no need to use ajax to load the images, unless you don't know what the list of images is going to be. If you're pulling the list of image names from a databse you could use ajax to get that data out and put it in an array, then you could assign that to the array `images`.

Comment: Thanks Rusty :) yes i have unknown no. of images that is why i'm thinking to use AJAX. Anyway thanks a lot to you.

Comment: Do you know how to use jQuery to get the data from your server via ajax? I'd probably use [$.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) to fetch the list of images from the server. Depending on how many images there are, you might only want to return 50 image names at a time, and then request more when you get to the end of the array.