# Jquery: how to create a simple AJAX image slider

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery/Ajax : image slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7252497/jquery-ajax-image-slider)

I'm new on Jquery but what I would like is to create a simple slider that load images with Ajax.

- how to **create a loop**
- how to set loop time speed
- how to load an image with Ajax request

Suppose I have an index.php with this:

```
<div id="output"></div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo $this->getUrl('somewhere/index/testajax') ?>",
            data: "id=1",
            success: function(response){
                $("#output").html(response);
            }
        });
    });
    //]]>
```

How can I create a loop that replicate the AJAX call ?

Comment: It is not as simple as you think. you need to preload the images. why wont you use a ready made plugin? there are zillions of these out there.

Comment: why you want to create custom one ,when there are tons of free plugins available

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949913/jquery-simple-image-slider-w-ajax http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5628108/simplest-ajax-photo-gallery  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7252497/jquery-ajax-image-slider

Comment: I want to create one plugin as I'd like to learn use jquery